# Signal Handler for SIGINT

Tags: c, linux, signals, handler, sigint

I am working on the following code. The program should be able to handle SIGINT with sigaction. So far, it's almost done, but I have come along two problems. 
**The first problem** is the program should print "Shutting down" and exit with status 1 if it receives 3 signals within 3 seconds.

**The second problem** is I am using **gettimeofday** and **struct timeval** to get the time in seconds regarding to the arrival times of the signals, but I failed here as well. When I tried it out, I got stuck in an infinite loop, even thought I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  3 times within 3 seconds. Also, the resulting seconds are quite big numbers.

I hope someone could help me to get these two problems done. Here's the code

```
int timeBegin = 0;

void sig_handler(int signo) {
   (void) signo;
   struct timeval t;
   gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
   int timeEnd = t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec;

   printf("Received Signal\n");

   int result = timeEnd - timeBegin;

   if(check if under 3 seconds) {  // How to deal with these two problems?
       printf("Shutting down\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   timeBegin = timeEnd   // EDIT: setting the time new, each time when a signal arrives. Is that somehow helpful?
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

    for( ;; ) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int timeEnd = t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec;
```

That won't work because `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` are different orders of magnitude. If you want microsecond accuracy, you'll have to store the value in a larger type (e.g. `int64_t`) and convert the seconds to microseconds.

```
   if(check if under 3 seconds) {  // How to deal with these two problems?
```

Well, what have you tried? You have several signals arriving at different times, you need to keep some state about them to know if all arrived within 3 seconds of each other.

Comment: You mean like *uint64_t timeEnd = t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec* and *uint64_t timeBegin = 0* ? How do I convert it to microseconds and why?

For the second problem, I just tried the following: if(result < 3) and I had a counter, but as I said above it did not work.

Comment: You have to convert because seconds and microseconds are different units... (you do know what "micro" means, right?)

Comment: Ok, I have to use the factor **1000000**. But still, how could I solve the the other problem with the arriving of several signals? Could you give me at least some more hints?

Comment: Try keeping information about when and how many signals arrived in variables outside the signal handler.